# Angular HttpClient thrown error status codes

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-httpclient

In angular documentation, it is stated that an HttpErrorResponse will be thrown for "non-successful HTTP status". ([See here](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpErrorResponse))

what are the non-successful statuses / non-successful status ranges for which an error will be thrown?
Are there cases for which a response will be valid even if HTTP status is "non-successful"?

**Context:**

In my particular case I have an authentication service. there is a condition in RxJs pipe switchMap that checks if status code is in the range of 200-399. It seems like a redundant check. I was wondering if it can be removed.

```
this.http.get<UserDto>(ConstantUrlName.AUTHENTICATION_URL, {observe: 'response'}).pipe(switchMap((resp: HttpResponse<UserDto>) => {
    const user = resp &&
                resp.status >= 200 && resp.status < 400 &&
                resp.body;
    ....
}))
```

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/f817e304053716d6a957c5c4863ea549ca9fbccd/packages/common/http/src/xhr.ts#L152-L156

Comment: Nice link from @jonrsharpe, It's what I wanted to say as well. This check is redundant because if the response status is `>= 400` it will be emitted on the error channel instead of the event channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to comment by @jonrsharpe we can see the answer in the [angular repository](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/f817e304053716d6a957c5c4863ea549ca9fbccd/packages/common/http/src/xhr.ts#L152-L156):

> ```
>   // ok determines whether the response will be transmitted on the event or
>    // error channel. Unsuccessful status codes (not 2xx) will always be errors,
>    // but a successful status code can still result in an error if the user
>    // asked for JSON data and the body cannot be parsed as such.
>    let ok = status >= 200 && status < 300;
> ```

Should probably be added in Angular's documentation.